# WYSIWYG on custom meta boxes while disabling main editor?

Tags: custom-post-types, wysiwyg

I'm working on creating a custom content type but I'm having a bit of a problem formatting the create and edit views.  I want to disable the main editor and focus only on the title, excerpt, and custom fields.  I have the following jQuery code that will add the WYSIWYG to my custom fields, and that works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */

        jQuery(document).ready( function () {
            if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" && typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "solution_problem");
                tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "solution_solution");
                tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "solution_people");

            }
        });

        /* ]]> */
</script>
```

But then when I remove the editor from the 'supports' argument in *register_post_type*:

```
'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','excerpt'), 'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
```

The default editor disappears but so do my custom WYSIWYGs. Anybody have any idea why this might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the exact same issue.  You have to include the editor in the supports argument array to get custom mce boxes to show.

I solved the issue by hiding it with CSS:

```
function move_posteditor( $hook ) {
    if ( $hook == 'post.php' OR $hook == 'post-new.php' ) {             
        add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'remove_edit_div' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'move_posteditor', 10, 1 );

    function remove_edit_div() {
        global $post;
        $post_type=get_post_type( $post->ID );
            if ( ( $_GET[ 'post_type' ] ) == 'custom_pt_name'  || (  $post_type == 'custom_pt_name') ) {
            ?>


                <style>#postdivrich { display: none; }</style>

    <?php }
```

Comment: Hmmmm ... I think I see what you're trying to do there, but the code is returning a HTTP Error 500 I can't trace (replacing the OR in the second line didn't do the trick)

Comment: Turns out that I can just add <style>#postdivrich { display: none; }</style> directly into the form and the editor is disappeared, no need for anything else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You really don't even have to do that, if you just enqueue the correct tiny-mce js and css files, you should be fine on actually removing the editor from the post-type supports array.